# AngularJS+ NodeJS App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I made an AngularJS App on its own and a NodeJS app seperately, but what I'm trying to do now is make a fusion of both. Either by putting the nodeJS app inside the AngularJS App or the other way around.

I know that it's better to have NodeJS app serve API that will be consumed by AngularJS App but I only want one server for the whole thing and I think it's doable since when I make an AngularJS app there is already a folder called "node_modules".

The structure of my project now is :

- AngularApp folders (in which there is the whole AngularJS app)
- node_modules (in which I loaded express, mysql and what I'd need in `Node.js` App)
- independently: `NodeApp.js` (the NodeJS app that contains the code of node)

However, when I run `app.js/index.html` it throws the following error: "can't get index.html", meaning that even though they're in the same project, AngularJS and NodeJS don't communicate. Can you please help me with this? How can I make the link between AngularJS and NodeJS if I want to make them both in the same Webstorm project?

Thanks in advance.

I found this in my research:
http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/02/13/how-to-use-nodejs-express-and-bower-to-create-angularjs-apps.aspx
it is what I want to do but I didn't understand everything since it's easier using Webstorm

Comment: Your confusing things. AngularJs is for developing front end applications. NodeJs is for developing server side applications. You cant "combine" the 2 in the way you seem to think. They have node modules because these are packages they use, it doesnt mean they are the same or you can simply combine them. node_modules and NodeJs are 2 different things. You should run your nodejs as to serve the content of your database. Then use your angular app to present this content to the user.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're asking here. Node.js and Angular are completely different technologies. Of course you can configure a Node.js http server to serve an Angularjs app. Perhaps posting some code could help me out?

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by combining them?

Comment: I realize the difference between AngularJS and NodeJS , the one is front-end and the other is back-end and that's what I'm trying to do : a complete appllication with the front and back-end in the same project

Comment: If I was to do only NodeJS, there is a possibility to have html files to display the views without using AngularJS but since there are features that I want to use in Angular (the routing between views, displaying dynamic data ..) I made an angularJS App, now I can't figure out how to link both of them

Comment: @glcheetham I'm hoping to have a complete application that has both front and back-end , now it's like I'm running two servers seperately: they don't even launch at the same port

Comment: It sounds to me like you downloaded a starter kit of some kind which includes a node server to serve up your angular app. This is no different from what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It's good to have 2 separate server for front-end and back-end. If you want to add other clients like iOS and android, it will be easy to use nodejs server API running separately.

But if you want just to have web-app with node and angularjs then you can serve angularJS code from nodejs.

Comment: @Shaffanhoon I didn't download anything, what I did before was use RESTful, AngularJS would get the data with http.get but now I'm using socket.io

Comment: @SandipNirmal that's what I'm trying to do: serve angularJS code from nodejs but I don't know how , can you please explain how it's done ?

Comment: You store the html page in a local folder and expose that page through an api:
`app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});`

Comment: You can have server and client code in different directories. And as suggested by Shaffanhoon, serve 
```index.html ``` or any starting file of your angular app from / route. You can use express's static feature for accessing client code (angular app).

```app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
```

here '/public' is path for your client directory. Which then you can access directly.

And serve index.html like

```app.get('/', function(req, res){ res.sendfile('/public/index.html'); });```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start a new app using [Express Generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) and check out the folder structure it creates.

I have a small app built with expressjs and angularjs, here's the folder structure:

- bin
- config
- models
- node_modules
- public

  - javascripts

    - In here all the angular crap (in sub folders of course)
- routes
- test
- views

  - index.html (this is my main html file, here is where angular loads)
- app.js

To do this I had to change the views engine to work with .html
Then when you access **localhost:3000** the server renders index.html (**localhost:3000/#/**) which loads angular and all the crap along. 
All my angular resources go to /api/yourModel.

So if you access **localhost:3000/api/yourModel** you are accesing the api directly.

For me this works just fine, and as you say you have everything together. The front end and the server in the same "project" sort of speak.

Comment: Thank you, when I make a nodeJS app this is kind of the structure that I get, when I do this will the routing be managed by AngularJS or in the subfolder routes ?

Comment: Well, you will be having two "routing". In the "server" side you will have to handle the different routes with express. Then in the front, with angular you will have to handle the front routes. For example using ui-router.

Comment: As for bower_components for AngularJS app, they go with public/javascripts too ?

Comment: I haven't used bower much, I think you can choose where to put the bower_components folder. Anyway I doubt you should put it inside public/javascripts. Maybe in public/.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by user1655756 , what I did was make a new nodeJS application and then instead of public, I injected the angularJS app folder.
Then as suggested by  Shaffanhoon in node.js I specified the path to my index.html and that's what worked for me ..
Thank you for all your help